# What are the limits of removing judicial recourse through arbitration clauses?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, terms-of-service, banking, arbitration

Suppose a FINRA-regulated financial institution is notorious for littering its service agreement with purportedly binding arbitration clauses, but then exercises a policy that amounts to depriving a customer of their assets without any lawful basis.

As their line of business is heavily regulated by statutes and regulations, surely there are certain immutable parameters as to how they should operate that cannot simply be contracted away with provisions in their terms of service that one may be required to sign on the dotted line of in opening an account.

**If such a company oversteps one of these parameters for lawful operation, are arbitration clauses binding in respect of these breaches, in removing judicial recourse for the customer in court, rather than in arbitration venues?**

**And what other scenarios give rise to causes of action that can immutably transcend arbitration clauses?**

Comment: To clarify - you are talking about civil remedies only?  Arbitration  clauses won’t  affect possible fraud  prosecution of course.

Comment: While beyond the scope of the question, the United States enforces arbitration clauses in many circumstances where other developed countries would not.

Comment: @ohwilleke Definitely an important observation.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite What about negligence?

Comment: Negligence can be an element in both civil and criminal cases.

Comment: So it seems like civil damages claims for negligence are confined to arbitration forums as well? (Ie, there's no out with which for civil negligence claims to bypass agreements to pursue disputes through arbitration?)

Answer (score 4):

> If such a company oversteps one of these parameters for lawful
> operation, are arbitration clauses binding in respect of these
> breaches, in removing judicial recourse for the customer in court,
> rather than in arbitration venues?

In this situation, the arbitration clause (assuming it was actually entered into) is binding and there is no meaningful judicial recourse through a civil lawsuit. It does not bar criminal prosecutions or administrative agency action.

> And what . . . scenarios give rise to causes of action that can
> immutably transcend arbitration clauses?

Civil actions seeking redress from sexual assaults are exempt from arbitration in the U.S., pursuant to H.R. 4445, the Ending Forced Arbitration of Sexual Assault and Sexual Harassment Act, which was signed into law on March 3, 2022.

Comment: Until I had read the second part of your answer, I was literally thinking to myself "wait, that can't be right: if you enter into a contract with your broker saying that you agree to pursue all disputes with them in arbitration, then they kidnap, rape, or murder you, surely a court won't care very much about the arbitration agreement."

But, having read the second part of your answer, are you saying that damages from kidnapping and murder (as they are not intrinsically sexual in nature) would need to be pursued in contractually designated arbitration forums?

Comment: But, what would determine whether an arbitration clause was "actually entered into"? Presumably a customer has agreed to a service agreement which presumably was drawn up to be as watertight as possible in removing the customer's recourse to judicial remedies, and presumably the lawyers drawing it up in that way did a decent job of doing so. These all seem like fairly sensible presumptions.

Comment: "are you saying that damages from kidnapping and murder (as they are not intrinsically sexual in nature) would need to be pursued in contractually designated arbitration forums?" Yes. It would be rare to have an arbitration agreement with someone who kidnaps or murders you, but it could happen. That wouldn't preclude a criminal prosecution or restitution in a criminal case, however. Arbitration applies to the forum for resolving civil disputes only, not criminal cases. There are doctrines to argue otherwise but they aren't ironclad.

Comment: @UBSOS23 In the context you describe there is generally not going to be any doubt that an arbitration agreement was entered into. FINRA brokers are usually very careful about that. But, suppose you just have two people entering into a contract and an authentic copy of the original contract isn't available - proving the existence or non-existence of an arbitration agreement can be non-trivial.

Comment: The sexual assault exemptions tend to come up in employee contract disputes than customer contract disputes.

Comment: Yes, of course the scenario would be highly unlikely, but then in my mind so was sexual assault by a digital/virtual broker company. Now that @hszmv clarified the context it makes a lot more sense why there would have been special exceptions specifically aimed at sexual assaults and how it is a situation that might happen more (ie in an employment context). And I was thinking more along the lines that separately of criminal prosecution, whether given it or absent it, there could be civil damage claims for those crimes, (see OJ simpson civil case).

Comment: @UBSOS23 The statute prohibiting arbitration of cases seeking civil remedies for sexual assault is quite new. "President Biden signed H.R. 4445, the Ending Forced Arbitration of Sexual Assault and Sexual Harassment Act (the Act), into law on March 3, 2022." https://www.perkinscoie.com/en/news-insights/new-law-ends-forced-arbitration-of-sexual-assault-and-sexual-harassment-disputes.html It was passed in response to cases where arbitration of such lawsuits was compelled. There are currently live lawsuits considering how to apply the effective date of the law.

Comment: How often would two individuals enter a relationship that they may want to subject to arbitration? I thought arbitration was generally something required in contracts that are drawn up by the more greatly leveraged party as a way to give themselves a greater advantage in case they mistreat their employees/customers. I assume that the scenario you envision is something that happens a decent amount, or you wouldn't have cited it, but I'm having trouble imagining how or when.

Comment: Oh, interesting.

Comment: @UBSOS23 Arbitration clauses are very common in all sorts of contracts, especially contracts with employees, with customers, with firms that enter into lots of small transactions with each other, in construction, and in international commerce. Employee arbitration went from 2% in 1992 to about 55% now (more stats at the link). https://www.epi.org/publication/the-growing-use-of-mandatory-arbitration-access-to-the-courts-is-now-barred-for-more-than-60-million-american-workers/ Consumer arbitration stats can be found at https://lawreview.law.ucdavis.edu/online/vol52/52-online-Szalai.pdf

Comment: So, anything that doesn't attract the recently introduced exemption for sexual assault is pretty much bindingly driving things into arbitration? That still doesn't seem right as I have read about exemptions being triggered in cases of class actions where the class has gotten certified.

Comment: @UBSOS23 Where there is an arbitration clause sometimes it is possible to arbitrate  the class action dispute in cases where there isn't a class action waiver. There is not a class action exemption from arbitration.

Comment: @UBSOS23  Meant to mention that Arbitration is used a great deal in employee contract disputes.   Kidnapping and Murder do not tend to come up in often in wrongful termination, hence why the sexual assault exception was made.  They didn't want sexist treatment of employees to be swept under the rug.

Comment: @ohwilleke What is a "class action waiver" - is it a provision within the arbitration clauses of the contract that exempt class actions from the arbitration clause(s)? If that is what it refers to, then why would such "class action waiver" provisions ever exist, since the contracts will almost always be drawn up by the bigger party, and it seems like it wouldn't be in their interests to add such special provisions to exempt class actions - or anything else, including sexual assault - from the arbitration clauses, since the incentive to include them in contracts seems to be to avoid actual 1/

Comment: ...civil court cases in as many situations as possible, if not in every situation that could ever arise, and class action waivers seem like something that would require extra proactive effort to put into a contract? 2/2

Comment: @hszmv makes complete sense.

Comment: @UBSOS23 Some employers thought arbitration clauses alone were sufficient to make a class action waiver, but then learned that you could have a class action in an arbitration forum. A class action waiver with an arbitration clause prevents that. A class action waiver without an arbitration clause prevents class actions in regular courts.

Comment: Another factor in the lack of an exemption to arbitration of wrongful death cases is that wrongful death cases are typically not brought by the decedent or the decedent's estate which would be bound by an arbitration clause. Instead, they are usually brought by statutorily designated next of kin. So the question of whether the arbitration clause is binding on them is at issue. There is also a doctrine that intentional tort liability can't be waived that could come into play, but usually a civil action for wrongful death is not against the perpetrator itself but instead a related third-party.